# compare data of two columns in same table and if values match print "right" if not print"wrong" using r programming?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
QuestionID  Correct_Option my chosen Answers
4050362705  4050369726  4050369728
```

this is my table, it has 100 values in each column. 
in this i want to check if correct option == my chosen answer 
and then print right/wrong in an adjacent column in this table. using r programming.how should i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R solution (also please in future provide sample data):

```
 df$answer_check <- ifelse(df$correct_option == df$my_chosen_answers,
                              "right",
                              "wrong")

df$answer_count <- ave(df$answer_check, df$answer_check, FUN = length)
```

Comment: See edited answer and upvote and accept it if you found it useful.

Comment: @PANKAJ please accept the answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your title and description do not match. If you want `TRUE`/`FALSE` values do

```
df$new_column <- df$Correct_Option == df$my_chosen_answers
```

Or if you want `"right"`/`"wrong"` do

```
df$new_column <- c("wrong", "right")[(df$Correct_Option == df$my_chosen_answers)+1]
```

Comment: what is this technique called    : df$new_column <- c("wrong", "right")[(df$Correct_Option == df$my_chosen_answers)+1]

Comment: @PANKAJ I don't know if it has any name as such. But it is form of vector indexing where `c("wrong", "right")` is the vector and you index them based on value in `Correct_Option` and `my_chosen_answers`.